# Javascript RegEx -- Selecting everything preceding a character only when ending with a specific phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use RegEx in JavaScript to remove the end of a sentence (string) after a comma, but only when a certain key phrase is ending the sentence.

For example, for key phrase `'StackExchange'` and sentence `RegEx is confusing me, John told StackExchange.`

I want to select just `RegEx is confusing me.`

---

For the sentence(s) / string:

> They couldn't figure out how to do it with RegEx. They searched for hours all around the web, before asking on StackExchange.

I want to select just:

> They couldn't figure out how to do it with RegEx. They searched for hours all around the web.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to do it using only regex? Break your problem in 2 simpler ones maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex pattern

```
^[^,]+(?=,.*StackExchange\.?$)
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/ENAYhG/1).

---

Or, if you want to check an optional period/dot at the end of the sentence (and store it to group #1), use the pattern

```
^[^,]+(?=,.*StackExchange(\.?)$)
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/TxOvg2/1).

---

### EDIT:

If you need to match everything before the **last** occurrence of comma, use

```
^.+(?=,.*StackExchange(\.?)$)
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/8nu0wG/1).

Comment: Thanks so much! Only thing is I want to select from the last occurrence of the comma (the one preceding StackExchange) in case there multiple comma, while this selects the first. Any chance you know offhand how to make it less greedy? Either way, tysm!

Comment: Again, you rock!